# Angular form validation and ngClass not working with multiple conditions

Tags: angular, validation, bootstrap-4

I want to apply the Bootstrap is-invalid class to textarea on form submission when both conditions are true. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<textarea 
    class="form-control" 
    rows="5" 
    placeholder="Add Text" 
    id="event"
    formControlName="incident"
    [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': incident.errors?.minlength && formSubmitAttempt === true } ">
  </textarea>
```

ANGULAR COMPONENT

```
formSubmitAttempt = false;

this.eventForm = new FormGroup({
incident: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(25)),
})

onSubmit(eventValue: Object) {
    this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
  }
```

Comment: You don't have access to the form control `incident` directly in the template but you do have access to the `FormGroup` called `eventForm`. You need to change `incident.errors?.minlength` to something like `eventForm.incident.errors.minLength` or something similar. More specific information [can be found here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context)

Comment: As a side note, `formSubmitAttempt === true` is redundant.

Comment: how so? formSubmitAttempt === true is false on init and only changed to true when the submit button is clicked. please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, not the cleanest but...

```
[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': eventForm.get('incident').errors && formSubmitAttempt == true || eventForm.get('incident').pristine && formSubmitAttempt == true} ">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use form properties and css classes

on html file:

```
<form  
    [formGroup]="form"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">


   <textarea [accepted]="form.valid" [disabled]="!form.valid"  > <textarea/>
</form>
```

on ccs file:

```
textarea:accepted {  // Your styles  }
textarea:disables{  // Your other styles  }
```